# Rotating plate and Casimir force

Tags: reference-frames, casimir-effect

Between two plates there exists because of the Casimir-effect a force.

Imagine if both (or one) of the plates start rotating. Would the force and direction change? Would there be an interaction between the virtual particles and the rotating plate that is different if they wouldn't be rotating?

Comment: Why would the rotation of the plates matter at all?

Comment: Casimir effect isnt a force , its the lack of a force.